# Spring framework version with Spring Data Neo4j

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-graph

Is there a version matrix for Spring framework core with Spring Data Neo4j?

I am looking for the (least) version of Spring framework core that is compatible (should be used) with Spring Data Neo4j 2.0.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use maven, and add just spring-data-neo4j, it will fetch all dependencies automatically. Even if you don't use maven, you can check the declared dependencies. From what I see in the [pom file](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/data/spring-data-neo4j/1.0.0.RELEASE/spring-data-neo4j-1.0.0.RELEASE.pom), it doesn't declare a specific version, which means it should be compatible with the latest version.

Comment: I thought so, but I have been facing numerous issues with 3.1.x. While everything works in 3.0.6. Reported @ http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?116896-Spring-3.1.x-issues-with-Neo4J

Comment: @Saket - I guess that would be because 3.1 is still RC. The latest release is 3.0.6.

Comment: i think so too...but am sure people wouldn't expect RC to be as unstable as this (functionally)!

Comment: There have been some internal changes in 3.1. in how beans are created especially with Java-Config and @TestContexts, we're still investigating this.

Comment: @MichaelHunger, any ideas when can I expect this to be resolved? I have been (unhappily) forced to revert over to 3.0.6 due to this. Also, do you mind taking up the post on the Spring forum - http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?116896-Spring-3.1.x-issues-with-Neo4J - and track that as a bug (if one does not exist)

Comment: I raised a JIRA issue (https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8824)  with the Spring Core Team, who will look into this for Spring 3.1.RC2.

Comment: I also added a test project for this to the SpringSource issues github project: https://github.com/jexp/spring-framework-issues/commit/fd9731670686e6c3423f1a409ca81b2c8709ac60, they still have to pull it.

Comment: It has been resolved for the next RC2 of Spring Framework (or you use their snapshot build), see https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8824